# call windows batch from shell

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell

I'm trying to run QGIS from the command-line on Windows.  QGIS provides a batch file for this, "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\qgis.bat". When I run this from within Emacs shell, the load hangs when QGIS tries to load it's Python interpreter.

To reproduce, start a new shell in Emacs with `M-x shell` and call `"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\qgis.bat"`. If instead  you first call `start` (to load a new prompt) and then call `"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\qgis.bat"` in that, QGIS loads.

Looking at `qgis.bat`, it calls several other batch files and also sets many environment variables. My guess is that some necessary variables aren't set when called directly from shell.

Is there a way to call the batch directly from Emacs shell so that QGIS loads?

Comment: When I enter `M-x shell` in emacs, I'm in bash. What are you in? `cmd /C qgis.bat` at the shell prompt would do it, but likely you still will get the popped up cmd window. GNU Emacs 29.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2021-10-12 Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Yes, I'm in `cmd`. I'm not running from MSYS2 or Cygwin or mingw.

Comment: You set `explicit-shell-file-name` or `shell-file-name` to `cmd.exe`? Because otherwise, you are not at the DOS prompt. You are in a shell produced by Emacs' `cmdproxy.exe`.

Comment: No, I have not set those. Indeed, `shell-file-name` is `"C:/emacs-27.1-x86_64/libexec/emacs/27.1/x86_64-w64-mingw32/cmdproxy.exe"`. (I guess at some level I am running mingw).

Comment: That's your answer. `start` is just running `cmd.exe` and that's why it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround to run, kill, and rerun QGIS:

```lisp
(defun rerun-qgis ()
  (interactive)
  ;; kill any running instance of QGIS
  (shell-command "taskkill /f /fi \"IMAGENAME eq qgis-bin.exe\"")
  ;; kill any lingering command window
  (shell-command "taskkill /f /t /fi \"WINDOWTITLE eq \\qgis\\ \"")
  ;; start QGIS; opens a command window which isn't needed beyond the
  ;; load. Retitle it "\qgis\" (because shell quoting is unfun and
  ;; that's what I got to work) so that we can kill it directly with
  ;; taskkill after load.
  (let ((proc (start-process "cmd" nil "cmd.exe" "/C" "start" "\"qgis\"" "cmd.exe" "/K" "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.20.3\\bin\\qgis.bat")))
    (set-process-query-on-exit-flag proc nil))
  ;; assume qgis loads in 3 seconds and kill the lingering command
  ;; window; I couldn't get a sentinel to work
  (run-at-time "3 sec" nil #'(lambda () (shell-command "taskkill /f /fi \"WINDOWTITLE eq \\qgis\\ \""))))
```